# Does an array or object's pointer/reference handle affect its size?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, memory-management, size

I know that if I have an array `int A[512]` that the reference A can point to the first element.  In pointer arithmetic, the memory is referenced as `A + index`.

But if I'm not mistaken, the pointer/reference also takes up a machine word of space.  Assuming an int takes up a machine word, does that mean that the 512 integers of the above array take up 513 words of space?

Is the same true/false for objects and their data members in C++ or C#?

*Update*: Wow you guys are fast.  To clarify, I'm interested in how C++ and C# *differ* in how they handle this, and how I can size objects to fit in a cache line (if possible).

*Update*: I have been made aware of the distinction between pointers and arrays.  I understand that arrays are not pointers, and that the pointer arithmetic I referenced above is only valid after the array has been converted to a pointer.  I don't think this distinction is relevant to the overall question however.  I'm interested in how both arrays and other objects are stored in memory in both C++ and C#.

Comment: It's more than that for C#, but not for C++. In C++ an array is effectively just a pointer to a block of memory. However in C++ there can be other overhead depending on where the memory came from. The heap has guard blocks and other housekeeping stuff to think about. In C# it is more like a C++ Vector - it's a class, which has a few other bytes of overhead. See here for all the gory details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to determine the overhead in C#?  I'd like to size some objects to exactly fit in a cache line.

Comment: That would be compiler/IDE specific. I'm not really sure how you would check that, besides maybe experimentation (check code size for different size arrays).

Comment: Any overhead will be specific to the implementation of the CLR & Garbage collector (the implementations can be different on different platforms & change between versions). IMHO, if you've valid concerns about these things (i.e. they will have an appreciable impact on your solution) then you shouldn't be using .net.

Comment: I'll take that under advisement.  The cross platform flexibility and reflection capabilities are appealing though, so I'd be interested in ways this overhead can be dealt with or managed so as not to greatly harm performance.  Collecting data at run-time about the machine we're running on seems like it might help.  I don't need pedal-to-the-metal speed, but I do want fast processing of a lot of small-ish objects.

Comment: I don't really see the point of your question. Of course you need pointers/references to access an array (be it explicitly passed to a function, or implicit in the code; note that even an array on the stack is accessed via pointer arithmetic similar to `STACK_POINTER - 5 + i`). That doesn't make them part of the size of that array. You don't consider the space for the instructions operating on an integer variable to be part of the size of that int, right? Moreover, this additional space doesn't matter: It's a very small constant and you couldn't do any better anyway.

Comment: The point of the question was to make sure that what you described above was in fact the case.  I didn't want to create arrays or objects that misaligned on cache lines because of size overhead that I was overlooking.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because any pointer is useless if it's right next to what it's pointing at ;-) If you're worried about alignment, be make sure there's a damn good reason to worry at all (even in many circles where cache utilization matters, alignment of arrays does not). If you do have a reason to worry, stop asking vague questions and learn about the implementation details on the platform you care about (e.g. learn how to allocate memory with specific alignment on your target OS).

Comment: Sure, if it's an array, but what about objects?  If an object internally references others, and all the referenced objects fit in a cache line together with the containing objects, it makes sense to allocate them together, no?  Does the compiler or GC do this?  Are objects broken up by their internal objects, or are they kept together?

Comment: And in the case of arrays, if I access an array reference, that reference is already taking up room somewhere, and then the prefetcher will likely be loading elements from the array.  I wanted to make sure that the reference wasn't stored in the first word of a cache line and then array elements were loaded in the following words of the same line.  From what people have said, it looks like array elements are instead loaded in a completely separate line.

Comment: I am researching how different platforms perform caching, but I wanted to know if C++ or C# have built-in size overhead that applies across platforms.  I'm looking for ways to parametrize object allocation so that I can tailor objects to a given platform at runtime.  The goal is to be multi-platform, not target a specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you're talking about fitting data into a cache line, the variable containing the reference and the actual data it refers to are not going to be located in near proximity.  The reference is going to wind up in a register (eventually), but it's probably originally stored as part of another object somewhere else in memory, or as a local variable on the stack.  The array contents themselves can still fit in cache lines when being operated on, regardless of whatever other overhead is associated with the 'object'.  If you're curious about how this works in C#, Visual Studio has a Disassembler view that shows the actual x86 or x64 assembly generated for your code.

Array references have special baked-in support at the IL (intermediate language) level, so you'll find that the way memory is loaded/used is essentially the same as using an array in C++.  Under the hood, indexing into an array is exactly the same operation.  Where you'll start to notice differences is if you index through arrays using 'foreach' or start having to 'unbox' references when the array is an array of object types.

Note that one difference as far as memory locality between C++ and C# can show up when you instantiate objects locally in a method.  C++ allows you to instantiate arrays on the stack, which creates a special case where the array memory is actually stored in close proximity to the 'reference' and other local variables.  In C#, a (managed) array's contents will always wind up being allocated on the heap.

On the other hand, when referring to heap-allocated objects, C# can sometimes have better locality of memory than C++, especially for short-lived objects.  This is due to the way that the GC stores objects by their 'generation' (how long they've been alive) and the heap compaction it does.  Short-lived objects are allocated quickly on a growing heap; when collected, the heap is also compacted, preventing the 'fragmentation' that can cause subsequent allocations in a non-compacted heap to be scattered in memory.

You can get similar memory locality benefits in C++ using an 'object pooling' technique (or by avoiding frequent small short-lived objects), but that takes a bit of extra work and design.  The cost for this, of course, is that GC has to run, with thread hijacking, promoting generations, compacting and reassigning references causing a measurable overhead at somewhat unpredictable times.  In practice, the overhead is rarely a problem, especially with Gen0 collection, which is highly optimized for a usage pattern of frequently allocated short-lived objects.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I'm fairly sure it's possible for an array to be stack allocated in C#, it just usually isn't.  That's up to the JIT compiler and CLR to decide, and usually objects are heap allocated, but this is not guaranteed.  That said, I'm aware that where a reference is stored and where the object it points to is stored can be vastly different locations.  I wasn't aware that arrays were managed differently as a special case.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a misunderstanding about arrays and pointers in C++.

#### The array

```
int A[512];
```

This declaration gets you an array of 512 `int`s. Nothing else. No pointer, no nothing. Just an array of `int`s. The size of the array will be `512 * sizeof(int)`.

#### The name

The name `A` refers to that array. It's not of pointer type. It's of array type. It is a name and it refers to the array. Names are simply compile-time constructs for telling the compiler what object you're talking about. Names don't exist at run-time.

#### The conversion

There is a conversion called array-to-pointer conversion that may occur *in some circumstances*. The conversion takes an expression which is of array type (such as the simple expression `A`) and converts it to a pointer to its first element. That is, in some situations, the expression `A` (which denotes the array) may be converted to an `int*` (which points at the first element in the array).

#### The pointer

The pointer that is created by array-to-pointer conversion exists for the duration of the expression it is part of. It is just a temporary object that appears in those particular circumstances.

#### The circumstances

An array-to-pointer conversion is a standard conversion and circumstances in which it may occur include:

- When casting from an array to a pointer. For example, `(int*)A`.
- When initialising an object of pointer type, e.g. `int* = A;`.
- Whenever glvalue referring to an array appears as the operand of an expression that expects a prvalue.

  This is what happens when you subscript an array, such as with `A[20]`. The subscript operator expects a prvalue of pointer type, so `A` undergoes array-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I wasn't aware of the distinction, as my C++ textbook (admittedly quite old) always treated arrays as pointers to indexes in terms of implementation (but not typing).

Answer (score 0):

No, the objects in CLR does *not* map to the "simple" memory mapping of `C++` (I immagine) you refer too. Remember that you can operate over objects in `CLR` using reflection, that means that *every* object has to have additional information (*manifest*) inside it. This already adds more memory that just plain content of the object, add to this also a *pointer* for `locking` management in multithreaded environment and you go far away in terms of *expected* memory allocation for `CLR` object.

Also remember that pointer size defers between `32` and `64` bit machines.

Answer (score 0):

An array, `int A[512]` takes up 512 * sizeof(int) (+ any padding the compiler decides to add - in this particularly instance, very likely no padding).

The fact that the array `A` can be converted to a pointer to int `A` and used with `A + index` uses the fact that in the implementation `A[index]` is almost always exactly the same instructions as `A + index`. The conversion to pointer happens in both cases, because to get to `A[index]`, we have to take the first address of the array A, and add `index` times `sizeof(int)` - whether you write that as `A[index]` or `A + index` doesn't make any difference. In both cases, `A` is referring to the first address in the array, and `index` the number of elements into it.

There is no extra space used here.

The above applies to C and C++.

In C# and other languages that use "managed memory", there is extra overhead to track each variable. This does not impact the size of the variable `A` itself, but it does of course have to be stored somewhere, and thus every variable, whether it's a single integer or a very large array, will have some overhead, stored somewhere, including the size of the variable and some sort of "reference count" (how many places the variable is used, and if it can be removed).

Comment: Note that the OP is talking about C# AND C++, so you'd better say which you're talking about (which seems to be C++)

Comment: That's correct, I'm interested in how both languages handle this.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing an array and pointer in C++.

An array of `int` is just that, it's an array of locations in memory, each taking up `sizeof(int)` in which you can store N-1 `int`s.

A pointer is a type which can point to a memory location, and takes up CPU register size in memory, so on a 32 bit machine, `sizeof(int*)` would be 32 bits.

If you want to have a pointer into your array, you do this: `int * ptr = &A[0];`  This points to the first element in the array.  Now you have the pointer taking up memory (CPU word size) and you have your array of `int`s.

When you pass an array to a function in C or C++, it *decays* to a pointer to the first element in the array.  That doesn't say that a pointer is an array, it says there is a *decay* from an array to a pointer.

In C# your array is a reference type, and you do not have pointers, so you don't worry about it. It just takes up the size of your array.

Comment: The declaration of an array creates a pointer in the literal sense (i.e. the name of the array is actually a pointer).

Comment: I didn't say an array is a pointer. I said the name of an array is technically a pointer and behaves identically even though it is not used identically.

Comment: @tmwoods The name of an array is the name of an array. It decays to a pointer in certain contexts, but it's *not* a pointer, technically or otherwise.

Comment: No, the name of an array is not technically a pointer, it's an array. All the rest is crap.

Comment: Then why does every intro to pointers ([example here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)) use the example of a declaration of an array as a pointer, defining it as a pointer?

Comment: What confuses people is that you can pass an array to a function that expects a raw pointer (C++)

Comment: @tmwoods Because they're written by people who don't know what they're talking about? cplusplus.com is notoriously bad both as reference and learning material.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, that is the confusion, but that is a decay to pointer and only happens in certain contexts.

Comment: @tmwoods fyi the only authoritative source is the standard, not some crappy tutorials on the Internet

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: This was just the first example from Google. I am out of town right now but I have at least three textbooks that I can remember using that use this example. I literally taught a lecture on this a week ago on this very point.

Comment: @tmwoods those textbooks are wrong then. There's a lot of crappy textbooks out there on C and C++.

Comment: @tmwoods [Come to the Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), we'll talk about it.

Comment: Easy people... I understand the distinction being made, and I apologize if that confuses my question, but I didn't think the distinction was particularly relevant for answering my question.  I'm interested in how objects (using pointers or references) and arrays (using some form of references) are handled in terms of memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning **native C++**:

> But if I'm not mistaken, the pointer/reference also takes up a machine word of space

A reference does not necessarily take space in memory. Per Paragraph 8.3.2/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

In this case, you can *use* `A` like a pointer, and indeed it does *decay* to a pointer when necessary (e.g. when passing it as an argument to functions), but the type of `A` is `int[512]`, not `int*`: therefore, `A` is **not a pointer**. For instance, you cannot do this:

```
int A[512];
int B;
A = &B;
```

There doesn't need to be any memory location used to store `A` (i.e. used to store the memory address where the array begins), so most likely your compiler will not allocate any extra bytes of memory for holding the address of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple different examples here, given that we even have several languages to discuss.

Let's start with the simple example, a simple array in C++:

```
int array[512];
```

What happens in terms of memory allocation here?  512 words of memory are allocated on the stack for the array.  No heap memory is allocated.  There is no overhead of any kind; no pointers to the array, no nothing, just the 512 words of memory.

Here is an alternate method of creating an array in C++:

```
int * array = new int[512];
```

Here we're creating an array on the heap.  It will allocate 512 words of memory with no additional memory allocated on the heap.  Then, once that is done, an address to the start of that array will be placed in a variable on the stack, taking up an additional word of memory.  If you look at the total memory footprint for the entire application, yes it will be 513, but it's worth noting that one is on the stack and the rest is on the heap (stack memory is much cheaper to allocate, and doesn't cause fragmentation, but if you overuse it or mis-use it you can run out more easily.

Now onto C#.  In C# we don't have the two different syntaxes, all you have is:

```
int[] array = new int[512];
```

This will create a new array object on the heap.  It will contain 512 words of memory for the data in the array, as well as a bit of extra memory for the overhead of the array object.  It will need 4 bytes to hold onto the count of the array, a synchronization object, and a few other bits of overhead that we don't really need to think about.  That overhead is small, and not dependent on the size of the array.

There will also be a pointer (or "reference", as would be more appropriate to use in C#) to that array that is placed on the stack, which will take up a word of memory.  Like C++, the stack memory can be allocated/deallocated very quickly, and without fragmenting memory, so when considering the memory footprint of your program it often makes sense to separate it.